# How to send request param in mutipart/formdata format with video ,image and text in retrofit(PUT Method)

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I tried multipart method,  Only text are uploaded successfully but how to send image and video in multipart.
Anyone tell me how to send text and video in put method using retrofit

- Using retrofit 2.3.0, I want to send text,image and video in PUT Method.
- But server get success but data not loaded it shows empty

**Code :**

**Retrofit interface :**

```
@Multipart
@PUT(CeceronmeUrl.LOCATION_COMMENT_EDIT)
Call<ResponseBody> editCommentWithImage(@Path("commentid") int locationId ,@Part MultipartBody.Part image/*,@Part MultipartBody.Part video */,@PartMap  HashMap<String, RequestBody> params/*,@Field("type")  int type*/ );
```

**Api call function :**

```
 private void editTipWithImage(final ProfileLocationViewParser.LocationDetail.Tip tip, final String trim, final AlertDialog alertDialog) {
    if (!BDevice.isInternetConnected(this)) {
        AlertUtils.showSnack(ProfileLocationListDetailExoActivity.this, txtLocationName, getResources().getString(R.string.check_your_internet_connection));
        return;
    }

    if (!isFinishing() && ceProgressDialog != null) {
        ceProgressDialog.show();
    }
    MultipartBody.Part displayPicture = null, displayVideo = null;

    String videoPath = null;
    String videoThumbPath = null;

    if (editCommentAttachment != 0) {
        if (editCommentAttachment == 1) {
            //photo
            File imgFolder = new File(ProfileLocationListDetailExoActivity.this.getExternalCacheDir(), "create_map/photo");
            String photoPath = FileUtils.getLatestFileFromDir(imgFolder.getAbsolutePath());

            if (photoPath != null) {
                try {
                    File file = new File(photoPath);
                    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), file);
                    displayPicture = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", file.getName(), requestFile);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else if (editCommentAttachment == 2) {
            //video
            File videoFolder = new File(ProfileLocationListDetailExoActivity.this.getExternalCacheDir(), "create_map/video");
            File videoThumbFolder = new File(ProfileLocationListDetailExoActivity.this.getExternalCacheDir(), "create_map/photo");

            videoPath = FileUtils.getLatestFileFromDir(videoFolder.getAbsolutePath());

            videoThumbPath = FileUtils.getLatestFileFromDir(videoThumbFolder.getAbsolutePath());
            if (videoPath != null) {
                try {
                    File file = new File(videoPath);
                    File fileThumb = new File(videoThumbPath);
                    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse("video/mp4"), file);
                    displayVideo = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("video", file.getName(), requestFile);
                    RequestBody requestFileThumb = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), fileThumb);
                    displayPicture = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", fileThumb.getName(), requestFileThumb);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    HashMap<String, RequestBody> params = new HashMap<>();

    params.put("type", createPartFromString(String.valueOf(editCommentAttachment)));
    params.put("comments", createPartFromString(TextUtils.encodeToBase64(trim)));
    if (isDelete == 1) {
        params.put("isdelete", createPartFromString(String.valueOf(isDelete)));
    }



    getApp().getWebServiceInterface().editCommentWithImage(Integer.parseInt(tip.comment_id), displayPicture, /*displayVideo,*/ params).enqueue(new RetrofitCallback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccessCallback(Call<ResponseBody> call, String content) {
            super.onSuccessCallback(call, content);
            if (ceProgressDialog.isShowing() && !isFinishing() && ceProgressDialog != null) {
                ceProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            getlocationViewWebservice();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailureCallback(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t, String message, int code) {
            super.onFailureCallback(call, t, message, code);
            if (ceProgressDialog.isShowing() && !isFinishing() && ceProgressDialog != null) {
                ceProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            AlertUtils.showAlert(ProfileLocationListDetailExoActivity.this, getString(R.string.app_name), message);
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: I had a similar problem, and I was thinking that everything is fine...I ended up finding out that the image / video I was sending was too big for the server to handle, so I had to compress the files. 

*Notice* I was still receiving success response from the server

***Edit:*** in my case was a `POST`

Comment: ok..Thank you very much @IonutJ.Bejan

Comment: Also, try to use `multipart/form-data` as type when you create `RequestBody`
  I hope you get this done